# Importing multiple .xlsx files into SQL Server using SSMS (Basic, not Enterprise)

Tags: sql-server, excel, file-upload, ssms

As the question states, I'm trying to upload roughly 2000 single-worksheet Excel files into a single SQL-Server database. The database has been set up using one of the excel files as a template and all the files have exactly the same layout. I'm hoping it's as simple as copying the rest of the data across from the files. Is there a way of moving all 2000 across at once instead of having to upload them individually using the SSMS import wizard.

Info:
Location of Excel files - C:\MyServer\MyUser\Desktop\Nominations

Database to add each excel table to - dbo.MyDatabase$

Using MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Can't add a diagram of the layout (too new to StackOverflow), but imagine a 12 column db and you're there. It's a really simple db.

I don't believe I have the multiple file option within the wizard unless I upgrade to Enterprise, which work won't allow until I complete a proof-of-concept test with these files.

Any help much appreciated. 
Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the wizard

```
INSERT DestinationTable
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
  'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\path\to\file.xlsx',
  'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]'
)
```